# From VS On for a date

Tags: prepositions

If I would like to express that the application has to be submitted on the two exact days mentioned below, can I use "from" as italic? Will the meaning change to "starting from that date" when using "from", or should "on" be used?

> Submit the Application Form ***from*** 4th October 2018 (Thursday), at 9:30 a.m. to 11:00 a.m. / 2:00 p.m. to 4:00 p.m. or ***from*** 5th October 2018 (Friday) at 9:30 a.m. to 11:00 a.m. / 2:00 p.m. to 4:00 p.m."

Comment: You submit something **on** a date, not **from** a date. You could also say something like: *The application form must be submitted* **between** *date 1 and date 2.* (But it would be awkward in your example sentence because you also include times.)

Comment: You could say “Applications will be accepted ***from*** October 15th ***to*** (or ***until*** or ***through***) October 19th”, to express a range.   (Note that “through October 19” explicitly means that applications will be accepted ***on*** October 19, “until October 19” probably means that they will *not* be accepted ***on*** October 19 (October 18 will be the last day), and “to October 19” is somewhat ambiguous.)   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  By the way, idiomatic ways of expressing a date include “October 4”, “October 4th”, “the 4th of October” and “4 October” — but not “4th October”. Also, we typically put a comma between the date (month & day) and the year; e.g., “October 4, 2018”.

Comment: @Scott - Agree with all you said, except that bit about "until" probably meaning not accepted on the 19th. If I read, "You have from the 15th until the 19th," I'd assume the 19th was included in the acceptable date range (though I'll admit it's ambiguous).